# Installing Anaconda while having Python 3.7 already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Complete noob here.

I am following MIT 6.0001 Introduction to Computer Science and Programming in Python. The instructor suggests to install Anaconda for this course. But I have Python 3.7 installed in my Windows 10 system already.

While installing Anaconda, I faced some problems which is currently beyond my level of understanding.

[image]

When I checked the box titled "Register Anaconda as my default Python 3.7" the following prompt was shown on the screen.

[image]

I don't know how to proceed further.
Please help me understand what these things mean and how will it affect my installation and future workflow.
Also, please suggest me best way proceed further.

Comment: well, it's impossible to help you with your problems if we don't know what they are...what is your question exactly?

Comment: at least tell me what should I do next

Comment: The images didn't show at first. How important is your current python installation? Could you just uninstall it?

Comment: I have made some projects on it. Also, I have done assignments using it.

Comment: This dialog in your last screenshot already explains what to do next. It's difficult to tell what you're asking for. Please, rephrase.

Comment: @sr9yar I installed anaconda without checking any of the two boxes. I can't see Anaconda Navigator in my start menu.

Answer (score 2):

You have two things you can do:

1.You can just go ahead and say "Ok"  You will get anaconda distribution installed alongside your normal python IDLE.
Your python installation should still work, like mine it works well.

2.You can also say: "cancel". 
  -Go back to your installed program and uninstall python.
. -Then start installation of anaconda.

Everything should run just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your projects will still work with Anaconda, just make sure you didn't save them inside the Python 3.7 directory.

You want to ADD the path to the environment, this allows you to just type `python.exe start.py` to run your scripts.

You want Anonconda to be the default interpreter because it is how you will keep your project packages maintained.  I would remove the old version, and install Anaconda, but you can technically have both on your system.

Comment: It shows a warning when I check the box titled "Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable."

Comment: Right... it's just asking if you are sure you want to do that.  So say yes or no depending on what you want to do.  

Yes to have both installed
No to uninstall 3.7 and install Anaconda.